# Update nested values in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Based on my code below, I am looking to set a variable to the req.body.update. I can't figure out how to accomplish this. When I set it to queryz nothing happens.

I am using mongoose for this.

```
app.put('/application/todoupdate/:id/:index', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('accessed put route');
    let item = 0;
    let queryz = "todos." + item + ".todoText";
    console.log(queryz);
    User.where({_id: req.params.id}).update({
      $set: {
        "todos.0.todoText": req.body.update
        // queryz: req.body.update
      }
    }).then(
      res.send(req.body.update)
    )
  });
```

My data base stucture is:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "77777777777"
},
"todos": [
    {
        "todoText": "req success",
        "timestamp": "7777777777777"
    },
    {
        "todoText": "something",
        "timestamp": "7777777777777"
    }
]
}
```

What I came to was which allowed me to access the lower level:

```
app.put('/application/todoupdate/:id/:timestamp', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('accessed put route');
    User.where({_id: req.params.id, "todos.timestamp": 
req.params.timestamp}).update({
      $set: {
        "todos.$.todoText": req.body.update
      }
    }).then(
      res.send(req.body.update)
    )
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to update nested array of objects

```
User.update(
    { _id: req.params.id }, 
    { "$set": { "todos.$.todoText": "hello" } }
)
```

and if you want to update all objects in array then you can use [`$[]` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

```
User.update(
    { _id: req.params.id }, 
    { "$set": { "todos.$[].todoText": "hello" } }
)
```

Comment: So how do I place a variable in that? I have no problem specifically stating what I want to update but if I pass an index as I did in the params how do I place that as the position.

Comment: You got me like 90% of the way there thanks man!